# VisualSVN Server - Delete user affects on history

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

When you delete a user from SVN, does it affect the history.  I couldnt find any documentation on it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No:**

1. History in SVN is immutable,
2. Removing user prohibit *future usage of this credentials*, but doesn't correlate in any way with authorship of previous revisions.